# “error”: “invalid_grant”, “error_description”: “Bad credentials”

Tags: spring, spring-security, postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yik0L.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CajZW.png)

Photo 1: This is the error that appears in the postman when trying to validate
¨Photo 2 : In the Authorization I do not get the preview request

This is the code in Spring for the AuthorizationServerConfig class, code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
       
    @Autowired
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
       endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
               .tokenStore(tokenStore())
               .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("angularapp")
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode("12345"))
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    } 

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }
    
    
}
```

This is the ResourceServerCoonfig class in spring attached code just in case this error:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/eventos").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
    
    
}
```

and this is the code of the SpringSecurityConfig class, I also attach code:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService usuarioService;
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(this.usuarioService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
    
    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.secret("{bcrypt}$2a$10$kwz.jnLVLwJOYTAp2r/oG.8tfAN/EC5dK1w5beLgfpuFT6Puprgq.")

use something like this,  spring security changed plain text passwords to bcrypt

[Check here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html)